# get error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dumps' when load model in HAYSTACK

Tags: elasticsearch, haystack

I trying to load `'bert-base-multilingual-uncased'` in [haystack](https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack) `FARMReader` and get the error:

> (huyenv) PS D:\study\DUANCNTT2\HAYSTACK\haystack_demo> &
> d:/study/DUANCNTT2/HAYSTACK/haystack_demo/huyenv/Scripts/python.exe
> d:/study/DUANCNTT2/HAYSTACK/haystack_demo/main.py 05/21/2021 00:12:58
>
> - INFO - faiss.loader -   Loading faiss. 05/21/2021 00:12:58 - INFO - faiss.loader -   Loading faiss. 05/21/2021 00:12:59 - INFO -
>   farm.modeling.prediction_head -   Better speed can be achieved with
>   apex installed from https://www.github.com/nvidia/apex . 05/21/2021
>   00:13:00 - INFO - faiss.loader -   Loading faiss. 05/21/2021 00:13:00
> - INFO - faiss.loader -   Loading faiss. 05/21/2021 00:13:01 - INFO - elasticsearch -   HEAD http://localhost:9200/ [status:200
>   request:0.018s] 05/21/2021 00:13:01 - INFO - elasticsearch -   HEAD
>   http://localhost:9200/cv [status:200 request:0.005s] 05/21/2021
>   00:13:01 - INFO - elasticsearch -   GET http://localhost:9200/cv
>   [status:200 request:0.009s] 05/21/2021 00:13:01 - INFO - elasticsearch
> - PUT http://localhost:9200/cv/_mapping [status:200 request:0.041s] 05/21/2021 00:13:01 - INFO - elasticsearch -   HEAD
>   http://localhost:9200/label [status:200 request:0.008s] 05/21/2021
>   00:13:01 - INFO - farm.utils -   Using device: CPU 05/21/2021 00:13:01
> - INFO - farm.utils -   Number of GPUs: 0 05/21/2021 00:13:01 - INFO - farm.utils -   Distributed Training: False 05/21/2021 00:13:01 - INFO
> - farm.utils -   Automatic Mixed Precision: None Some weights of the model checkpoint at bert-base-multilingual-uncased were not used when
>   initializing BertForQuestionAnswering: ['cls.predictions.bias',
>   'cls.predictions.transform.dense.weight',
>   'cls.predictions.transform.dense.bias',
>   'cls.predictions.decoder.weight', 'cls.seq_relationship.weight',
>   'cls.seq_relationship.bias',
>   'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.weight',
>   'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.bias']
> - This IS expected if you are initializing BertForQuestionAnswering from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another
>   architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model
>   from a BertForPreTraining model).
> - This IS NOT expected if you are initializing BertForQuestionAnswering from the checkpoint of a model that you
>   expect to be exactly identical (initializing a
>   BertForSequenceClassification model from a
>   BertForSequenceClassification model). Some weights of
>   BertForQuestionAnswering were not initialized from the model
>   checkpoint at bert-base-multilingual-uncased and are newly
>   initialized: ['qa_outputs.weight', 'qa_outputs.bias'] You should
>   probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it
>   for predictions and inference. 05/21/2021 00:13:21 - WARNING -
>   farm.utils -   ML Logging is turned off. No parameters, metrics or
>   artifacts will be logged to MLFlow. 05/21/2021 00:13:21 - INFO -
>   farm.utils -   Using device: CPU  05/21/2021 00:13:21 - INFO -
>   farm.utils -   Number of GPUs: 0 05/21/2021 00:13:21 - INFO -
>   farm.utils -   Distributed Training: False 05/21/2021 00:13:21 - INFO
> - farm.utils -   Automatic Mixed Precision: None 05/21/2021 00:13:21 - INFO - farm.infer -   Got ya 3 parallel workers to do inference ...
>   05/21/2021 00:13:21 - INFO - farm.infer -    0    0    0  05/21/2021
>   00:13:21 - INFO - farm.infer -   /w\  /w\  /w\ 05/21/2021 00:13:21 -
>   INFO - farm.infer -   /'\  / \  /'\ 05/21/2021 00:13:21 - INFO -
>   farm.infer - Exception ignored in: <function Pool.**del** at
>   0x000001BBA1DC9C10> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
>   line 268, in **del**   File
>   "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py",
>   line 362, in put AttributeError: **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dumps'**

This is my main.py file:

```py
from haystack.reader.farm import FARMReader
from haystack.document_store.elasticsearch import ElasticsearchDocumentStore
from haystack.retriever.sparse import ElasticsearchRetriever

document_store = ElasticsearchDocumentStore(
    host="localhost",
    username="",
    password="",
    index="cv",
    embedding_dim=768,
    embedding_field="embedding")
retriever = ElasticsearchRetriever(document_store=document_store)
reader = FARMReader(model_name_or_path='bert-base-multilingual-uncased')
```

**NOTICE**: My elasticsearch server has been started successfully!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with multiprocessing on Windows. You can disable multiprocessing for the `FARMReader` like this:

```
...
reader = FARMReader(model_name_or_path='bert-base-multilingual-uncased', num_processes=0)
```

See also the [docs](https://haystack.deepset.ai/docs/latest/apireadermd#Class-FARMReader) for more details.